# CSS - Deactivate top div

Tags: html, css, rotation

How can I deactivate the top DIV so that I can select what's under it?

Check what I did here:
http://jsfiddle.net/zE5Ze/2/

```
#triangle_w {
    width: 1000px;
    height: 178px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: fixed;
    left: -24px;
    top: -82px;
    /*outline: 1px solid pink;*/

    -moz-transform: rotate(-10deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-10deg);
}
#triangle {
    width: 961px;
    height: 176px;
    background: url('http://i.imgur.com/FTGa2.png') no-repeat;
    position: absolute;
    left: 10px;
    bottom: -80px;
    /*outline: 1px solid red;*/

    -moz-transform: rotate(10deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(10deg);
}
#triangle #menu {
    -moz-transform: rotate(-10deg);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-10deg);
    /*outline: 1px solid red;*/
}
```

Without the rotation: http://jsfiddle.net/zE5Ze/5/
As you can see, the areas inside the red outline are not selectable.

Is there a way to do this without having to fiddle with CSS rotations?
I'd like to deactivate the triangle, and leave only the menu and the thumbs active.

Answer (score 1):

#### Simple. Give a `z-index`.

```
#triangle #menu a {z-index: 5;}
```

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zE5Ze/3/

Or set a **`width`**!

```
#triangle_w {width: 100px;}
```

#### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zE5Ze/4/

Comment: They already have a width. And that doesn't deactivate the top div without having to rotate it.

Comment: Without the rotation: http://jsfiddle.net/zE5Ze/5/
As you can see, the areas inside the red outline are not selectable.

Comment: @x03k The `width` is too much buddy, `930px`! Change it to `100px` or something!

Comment: I can't change the design of the project.

Comment: Can you over-ride the CSS? Add another rule na?

Comment: Yes. Please read the question, because your solutions don't make sense.